# Prepopulate input from previous SELECT option with PHP & SQL

Tags: php, jquery, sql

I have a couple of SELECT that get Make & Models, I want to pre-populate a rating into an input box when the Model is chosen. This below is what I have, but it keeps giving me a page500 error each time I try something.

Not sure where I've gone wrong

this is from my class.php

```
public function ShowEfficRating() {
        include "db.php";
        $sql = "SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, Efficiency * 100) + '%' FROM Rating WHERE Model = $_POST[model]";
        $res = odbc_exec($cnn, $sql);
        $effic = $res
    }
    return $effic;
```

This is the jquery from my main page

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var model = $("select#model").val();
        $.post("selecttype.php", {model:model}, function(data) {
            return $('input[name="efficrating"]').val();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- Your `return` statement is outside your function.
- Never pass $_POST data directly into a query.  It must always be sanitized.
- Passing unquoted string constant values directly into $_POST (e.g. `$_POST[model]`) is deprecated.  Use `$_POST['model']` instead.

[edit to address using returned data:]

Take a look at the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).  They show that the data returned from the ajax request will be passed in to the callback function as the first parameter.  Consider this modified version of your original ajax call:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var model = $("select#model").val();
        $.post(
            "selecttype.php", 
            {model:model}, 
            function(data) {
                $('input[name="efficrating"]').val(data);
            }
        );
    });
</script>
```

It's now taking the data returned from the ajax call and using it to set the value of the input.

Comment: I made those changes and still when my main page loads it returns as a page500 error

Comment: If making the changes still results with a page500 error, where have I gone astray?

Comment: There could be errors elsewhere in the code, as well.  Try reducing your code to the simplest case and, when you get that working, start adding things back.

Comment: I've looked at this again slowly, managed to get the page to run, it no longer gives a page500 error, I select the model and that populates the SELECT box but nothing then happens with the efficrating input. how can I output the model as I've tried to echo $_POST & $_GET dont return anything. how can I out put this? I tried this also and still no joy `$('input[name="model"]').blur(function(){
            $('input[name="efficrating"]').val(function(){
                return $('input[name="model"]').val();
            });     })`

Comment: Edited to address question.

Comment: When Im posting the $_POST['model'] into the sql, as I'm posting a string is this still right to do so or do I need "'. $_POST['model'] .'"? I found the error was using the function in with my functions for the selects, so I used a new class.php with just this function, this again just filters the model I want but nothing is shown in the  efficrating input

Comment: '<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var model = $("select#model").val();
        $.post(
            "inputtype.php", 
            {model:model}, 
            function(data) {
                $('input[name="efficrating"]').val(data);
            }
        );
    });
</script>` My inputtype.php `include "assets/configs/input.class.php";
    echo $opt->ShowEfficRating();`

Comment: and the input.class.php `class SelectList {

        public function ShowEfficRating() {
            include "db.php";
            $sql = "SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, Efficiency * 100) + '%' FROM .Rating WHERE Model = $_POST['model'] ";
            $res = odbc_exec($cnn, $sql);
            $reffic = $res
            return $effic;
        }

    }
$opt = new SelectList();`

Comment: I've followed the link you posted and came up with this ` $("section5").submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var $form = $(this),
                modelname = $form.find("select#model").val(),
                url = "inputtype.php";

            var posting = $.post(url, { modelname: model });

            posting.done(function (data) {
                $('input[name="efficrating"]').val(data);
            });
        });` for some reason I can't see, when I run the page I choose my model and nothing outputs to the input[name="efficrating"]

Comment: Yes, in your query, you do need to break the $_POST array value out of your string as you suggested (or wrap it in curly braces), but again, placing unsanitized strings directly into queries (or into much of anything) is a huge no-no.  Do not ever do this in production code.

Comment: You should inspect the AJAX response to make sure you're actually getting the data back from the AJAX call.  Using your favorite browser's developer tools (if your favorite browser is still IE, that's probably about to change...), you can inspect network requests.  Open the developer tools by pressing F12, find the network requests (usually a tab labelled "Net" or "Network"), trigger your AJAX request, inspect it and take a look at the response.  If it doesn't contain the data you expect, you still have an error in the PHP code.

Comment: I am still having issues with this, I just want to use the variable from my SELECT to feed the sql to then output the result in the Input box. This is the jquery I have on my page `<script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
         var model = $("select#boilermodel").val();
         $.post(
             "assets/datafetch/getdata.php", 
             {model:boilermodel}, 
             function(data) {
                $('input[name="saprating"]').val(data);
             }
         );
     });
    </script>` and this is the php script

Comment: `include '../configs/db.php';    
    $boilermodel = $_POST['boilermodel'];
    $saprs = odbc_exec($cnn, "SELECT SAP2009AnnualEfficiency FROM blr.BoilerModel WHERE BoilerModel = '".$boilermodel."' ");
    while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($saprs)) {
        $json[] = $row
    }
    echo json_encode($json);` Where am I going wrong? when I run the page, select what I want, nothing happens in the Input box

Comment: can anyone help with this?